# read multiple files by python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to open several files, say 50 files named 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, ... so on and have to read them one by one. The way I can read them is

```
data = loadtxt("1.txt", float)
```

So that the file name is used as string and I can't use any loop to read them. And it is very tedious to read each files individually. Is there any way to use a loop to read all files? 
Thanks.

Comment: Is the question how to generate filenames running from 1.txt. to XX.txt?

Comment: Thank you all who answers my question. I've started learning python couple of days ago. May be my question is silly. Please don't give me negative votes. Otherwise my endeavour to learn python through this site will be finished. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *easily* construct a string with an integer in it:

```
>>> '{0}.txt'.format(1)
'1.txt'
```

Do that in a loop:

```
for i in range(50):
    data = loadtxt('{0}.txt'.format(i + 1), float)
```

and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 3):

Quite easy:

```
for i in range(1,51):
   data = loadtxt('{0}.txt'.format(i),float)
   #process data here.
```

Old-school string interpolation will work too if you prefer c-style string formatting:

```
datafile = '%d.txt' % (i)
```