# How to read multiple images and create a 3D matrix with them?

Tags: python, image-processing, matrix, multidimensional-array, concatenation

I have a bunch of images (300 images of 400 X 400 pixels) with filenames like:

- 001.bmp
- 002.bmp
- 003.bmp
- ...

First, I tried reading one of them, e.g. using `imread` I get a (400L, 400L, 3L) matrix, the problem is the 3L (I think is RBG format), so the question here is: how can I read them and get a (400L, 400L, 1L) matrix that I need to proccess them?

Second, I tried to read the 300 images using a loop like the following:

```
data = np.zeros((400,400,300))
for i in range(300):
    data[:,:,i] = imread('{0}.bmp'.format(i))
```

but it doesn't work, very probably my code is wrong. Actually doing this, I want to concatenate each (300) image data (400 X 400) into a matrix of (400 X 400 X 300).

When trying to use:

```
data[:,:,i] = imread('{0}.bmp'.format(i))
```

search for `'1.bmp'` and not `'001.bmp'`, but due to the list go from 000 to 299, I got a problem with that and I cant write `'00{0}.bmp'.format(i)` to complete the filename, because for two- and three digits numbers I got `'0012.bmp'` or `'00123.bmp'`

Well, after hours, I got to do this

```
arrays = []
for number in range(0, 299):
    numstr = str(number).zfill(3)
    fname = numstr + '.bmp'
    a = imread(fname, flatten=1)
    arrays.append(a)
data = np.array(arrays)
```

This code its work well. Thankyou, for give me clues!

Answer (score 3):

First, you are right that the last dimension are the color channels. I assume you want a grayscale image, which you can get with:

```
data = imread(fname, flatten=1)
```

That comes from the imread documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html).

Second, your issue with the loop can be due to a couple of things. First, I don't see indentation in the code in your post, so make sure that is there on the loop body in the code that you are actually trying to run. Second, the code has a ".txt" extension. Are you sure you don't actually want ".bmp"?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for in other posts and find some similar that I wanted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406927/read-multiple-files-by-python). Actually, I tried to follow the post but I dont see, where we can concatenate. You are wright with the identation and the extension, I just copied wrongly. So thanks, you help with my first question, actually I was using imread from pyplot, now I change to imread from scipy that accept the keyword argument flatten. Now, How could read and concatenate all this 2D-arrays (each image) into a 3D-array. I need do a loop, but how?

Comment: My apologies, I neglected to address that padding issue. You have converted to a string and called zfill(), which is fine, but you can also pad the filename with zeroes in situ with your format specifier , like: "{0:03d}.txt".format(i+1). the first '0' is refers to the zeroth argument to format() and the second zero indicates zero padding, and '3' tells it to pad to a 3 digits.